# Where are TPM 2.0 selftest messages logged?

Tags: logs, messaging, tpm

Hopefully, this is a simple question regarding hardware I'm just now learning how to use: the TPM.

My laptop has a TPM 2.0, and I need to become familiar with some basic functionality offered by the `tpm2-tools` package. To start, I confirmed that the `tpm2-abrmd` (the daemon) service is active. Then I ran

```bsh
sudo tpm2_selftest -V
```

and was expecting a verbose output in the terminal. However, nothing is output in the terminal when I execute the command. The [manual](https://www.mankier.com/1/tpm2_selftest) describes the messages sent by the TPM but not *where* they are sent/logged. I checked `/var/log/syslog` but found nothing.

Does anyone know where the messaging data is stored? Or if it *is* stored, for that matter?

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo tpm2_selftest -f -V`?

Comment: The process takes longer to complete, but the output is the same (that is, there is no output in the terminal window).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special here, [the source](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/lib/log.h#L21) shows it just logs to standard output.

There's simply not any more logging done. Not too bad, the source is all there (as linked above), and there's little guesswork involved!

By the way, very few modern linuxes still use `/var/log/syslog`, most use journald, which you can query using `journalctl -e` (jumping directly to the most recent message).

Comment: If it logs to standard output, then why can't I see anything if I direct the filestream to a text file? ```sudo tpm2_selftest -V > tpm2_output``` contains no information after executing in the terminal.

Comment: I answered that in the second sentence.